# Render.com: HttpOnly Cookie not being set in browser storage when doing res.cookie between Web Services

Tags: cookies, nestjs, cross-domain, samesite, httponly

I have a NestJs app that uses HttpOnly cookies for authentication. In development everything works perfectly. My NextJs client (http://localhost:4200) uses Graphql to send a login request to my NestJs server (http://localhost:3333), which sets httpOnly cookies in the response, and then the client successfully adds the cookies to the browser storage.

However, when I deploy both apps to Render.com, everything works apart from the final step. The cookies are successfully received in the response, but are not added to the browser storage. Interestingly, if I use the GraphQL playground of the deployed production server to make the login request, everything works. So, clearly, the issue seems to be that the request is coming from a subdomain.

**My production configuration:**

Client: https://swingapple-web-staging.onrender.com
Server: https://swingapple-api-staging.onrender.com

**Cookies settings (Server):**

```
sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'none' : 'lax',
secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '.onrender.com' : undefined
```

**Nestjs's GraphQLModule settings (Server):**

```
playground: true,
introspection: true,
autoSchemaFile: true,
sortSchema: true,
context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
cors: {
    credentials: true,
    origin: [process.env.CLIENT_URL, 'http://localhost:4200']
}
```

**Relevant Nest main.ts config (server):**

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
```

**graphql-request settings (client):**

```
credentials: 'include'
```

I've spent days trying to figure this out so any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After speaking with the Render.com support, they informed me that `onrender.com` (the domain for their subdomains) is on the public suffixes list, which means cross site cookies won't work. The solution was to add a custom domain for both Web Services (which obviously has to be the same e.g. app.my-custom-domain.com and api.my-custom-domain.com). I did this, and now everything is working as intended!

Comment: thank you! took forever to figure this out

Comment: No worries Pear, happy to help!

Comment: hi, will this work for the free tier for render.com? I'm looking for free options.

Comment: Based on the render.com docs, your first 25 custom domains are indeed free: https://render.com/docs/custom-domains